# Concurrent S3 File Upload via Kotlin Coroutines

Tags: amazon-s3, kotlin, upload, kotlin-coroutines

I need to upload many files to S3, it would take hours to complete that job  sequentially. That's exactly what Kotlin's new coroutines excels in, so I wanted to give them a first try instead of fiddling around again with some Thread-based execution service.

Here is my (simplified) code:

```
fun upload(superTiles: Map<Int, Map<Int, SuperTile>>) = runBlocking {
    val s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion("eu-west-1").build()
    for ((x, ys) in superTiles) {
        val jobs = mutableListOf<Deferred<Any>>()
        for ((y, superTile) in ys) {
            val job = async(CommonPool) {
                uploadTile(s3, x, y, superTile)
            }
            jobs.add(job)
        }
        jobs.map { it.await() }
    }
}

suspend fun uploadTile(s3: AmazonS3, x: Int, y: Int, superTile: SuperTile) {
    val json: String = "{}"
    val key = "$s3Prefix/x4/$z/$x/$y.json"
    s3.putObject(PutObjectRequest("my_bucket", ByteArrayInputStream(json.toByteArray()), metadata))
}
```

The problem: the code is still very slow and logging reveals that requests are still executed sequentially: a job is finished before the next one is created. Only in very few cases (1 out of 10) I see jobs running concurrently.

Why does the code not run much faster / concurrently? What can I do about it?

Comment: Uneducated guess: move `val s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder...` inside the async section so that you have multiple clients?

Comment: that did not work neither. my uneducated guess now is that `putObject` is blocking request, something coroutines can't change

Comment: Exactly. It seems like the S3 SDK does not support non-blocking IO (via NIO), so you need one thread per upload. You can still run multiple in parallel, but it's probably not advisable to do them _all_ in parallel. At some point you will also just be limited by your network bandwidth.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Kotlin coroutines excel when you work with *asynchronous* API, while `AmazonS3.putObject` API that you are using is an old-school blocking, synchronous API, so you get only as many concurrent uploads as the number of threads in the `CommonPool` that you are using. There is no value in marking your `uploadTile` function with `suspend` modified, because it does not use any suspending functions in its body.

The first step in getting more throughput in your upload task is to start using asynchronous API for that. I'd suggest to look at [Amazon S3 TransferManager](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/amazon-s3-transfermanager/) for that purse. See if that gets your problem solved first.

Kotlin coroutines are designed to help you to combine your async APIs into a easy-to-use logical workflows. For example, it is straightforward to adapt asynchronous API of `TransferManager` for use with coroutines by writing the following extension function:

```
suspend fun Upload.await(): UploadResult = suspendCancellableCoroutine { cont ->
    addProgressListener {
        if (isDone) {
            // we know it should not actually wait when done
            try { cont.resume(waitForUploadResult()) }
            catch (e: Throwable) { cont.resumeWithException(e) }
        }
    }
    cont.invokeOnCompletion { abort() }
}
```

This extension enables you to write very fluent code that works with `TransferManager` and you can rewrite your `uploadTile` function to work with `TransferManager` instead of working with blocking `AmazonS3` interface:

```
suspend fun uploadTile(tm: TransferManager, x: Int, y: Int, superTile: SuperTile) {
    val json: String = "{}"
    val key = "$s3Prefix/x4/$z/$x/$y.json"
    tm.upload(PutObjectRequest("my_bucket", ByteArrayInputStream(json.toByteArray()), metadata))
        .await()
}
```

Notice, how this new version of `uploadTile` uses a suspending function `await` that was defined above.